# PlacePicker API of the same app works for one device, not for another

Tags: android, google-api, google-places-api

I have a Sony Xperia SP with CM 13 (marshmallow) and a Redmi Note 3 (MIUI 7), both of which I use for testing my apps. I created a simple app that uses the PlacePicker API, and updates a TextView with the co-ordinates of the location selected by the user in the PlacePicker activity. It works completely fine on my Sony, while on my Redmi, the PlacePicker activity does not open, and the onActivityResult gets called with a resultCode of 0.

PS: I followed all the instructions from https://developers.google.com/places/android-api/placepicker and I also added the  tag for the API key in the manifest file by following instructions from https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android-api/signup

Edit: The problem isn't with the API key, because problem like that would result in atleast the PlacePicker activity opening for 1-2 seconds and then closing. In my case, the PlacePicker activity does not open at all.